# failure in insert inside stored function

Tags: mysql, function, insert

I have a table with some race results

```
CREATE TABLE `fls119_ergebnisse` (
  `start_nr` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `rennen` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  `zeit1` time(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00.000',
  `zeit2` time(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00.000',
  `zeit3` time(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00.000',
  `zeit4` time(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00.000',
  `zeit5` time(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00.000',
  `zeit6` time(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00.000',
  `zeit7` time(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00.000'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `fls119_ergebnisse` (`start_nr`, `rennen`, `zeit1`, `zeit2`, `zeit3`, `zeit4`, `zeit5`, `zeit6`, `zeit7`) VALUES
('0001', 21, '08:59:59.000', '09:03:59.000', '09:08:04.000', '09:12:11.000', '09:16:19.000', '09:20:32.000', '09:24:36.000'),
('0002', 21, '09:00:59.000', '09:04:59.000', '09:09:03.000', '09:13:08.000', '09:17:15.000', '09:21:28.000', '09:25:33.000'),
('0003', 21, '09:02:00.000', '09:06:03.000', '09:10:07.000', '09:14:12.000', '09:18:20.000', '09:22:33.000', '09:26:41.000'),
('0004', 21, '09:03:00.000', '09:06:59.000', '09:11:09.000', '09:15:17.000', '09:19:29.000', '09:23:45.000', '09:27:55.000'),
('0005', 21, '09:03:59.000', '09:08:09.000', '09:12:13.000', '09:16:15.000', '09:20:19.000', '09:24:30.000', '09:28:35.000'),
('0006', 21, '09:05:00.000', '09:09:01.000', '09:12:59.000', '09:16:56.000', '09:20:57.000', '09:25:02.000', '09:28:59.000'),
('0007', 21, '09:05:59.000', '09:10:13.000', '09:14:28.000', '09:18:42.000', '09:23:00.000', '09:27:22.000', '09:31:36.000'),
('0008', 21, '09:06:59.000', '09:11:09.000', '09:15:20.000', '09:19:34.000', '09:23:49.000', '09:28:09.000', '09:32:19.000'),
('0009', 21, '09:07:59.000', '09:12:05.000', '09:16:09.000', '09:20:14.000', '09:24:23.000', '09:28:37.000', '09:32:48.000'),
('0010', 21, '09:08:59.000', '09:13:23.000', '09:17:51.000', '09:22:19.000', '09:26:43.000', '09:31:09.000', '09:35:24.000'),
('0011', 21, '00:00:00.000', '00:00:00.000', '00:00:00.000', '00:00:00.000', '00:00:00.000', '00:00:00.000', '00:00:00.000'),
('0012', 21, '09:10:59.000', '09:15:10.000', '09:19:24.000', '09:23:33.000', '09:27:43.000', '09:32:00.000', '09:36:12.000'),
('0013', -1, '00:00:00.000', '00:00:00.000', '00:00:00.000', '00:00:00.000', '00:00:00.000', '00:00:00.000', '00:00:00.000'),
('0014', -1, '09:19:59.000', '09:23:36.000', '09:27:15.000', '09:30:55.000', '09:34:36.000', '09:38:19.000', '09:41:53.000'),
('0015', -1, '09:20:59.000', '09:24:36.000', '09:28:21.000', '09:32:05.000', '09:35:48.000', '09:39:35.000', '09:43:17.000'),
('0016', -1, '09:21:59.000', '09:25:33.000', '09:29:14.000', '09:32:52.000', '09:36:28.000', '09:40:11.000', '09:43:39.000'),
('0017', -1, '09:22:59.000', '09:26:31.000', '09:30:11.000', '09:33:49.000', '09:37:27.000', '09:41:12.000', '09:44:49.000'),
('0018', -1, '09:23:59.000', '09:27:32.000', '09:31:15.000', '09:34:58.000', '09:38:41.000', '09:42:30.000', '09:46:09.000'),
('0019', -1, '09:24:59.000', '09:28:45.000', '09:32:34.000', '09:36:19.000', '09:40:03.000', '09:43:54.000', '09:47:35.000'),
('0020', -1, '00:00:00.000', '00:00:00.000', '00:00:00.000', '00:00:00.000', '00:00:00.000', '00:00:00.000', '00:00:00.000');
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE `fls119_ergebnisse`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`start_nr`);
COMMIT;
```

I want to store the resulting place in a different table with

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS FortyTwo;
DELIMITER //
SET @place = 1//
SET @times = cast('00:00:00.000' as TIME(3))//
SET @y = 1//
CREATE FUNCTION `FortyTwo`(xtime TIME(3), xstartnr varchar(10)) RETURNS INT
    BEGIN
    DECLARE x INT;
        IF @times = xtime THEN
          SET x = @place;
        ELSE
          SET @place = @y;
          SET x = @place;
          SET @times = xtime;
        END IF;
    SET @y = @y +1;
    insert into fls119_platzierung (start_nr, platz, zeit) VALUES (xstartnr, x, xtime) on duplicate key update platz = x, zeit = xtime;
    RETURN x;
END//
DELIMITER ;
select FortyTwo(timediff(zeit7, zeit1), start_nr), start_nr, timediff(zeit7, zeit1) from fls119_ergebnisse erg where timediff(zeit7, zeit1) > 0  and rennen = 21
ORDER BY timediff(zeit7, zeit1) asc
```

The result of that call look correct:

1. 0006    00:23:59.000
2. 0002    00:24:34.000
3. 0005    00:24:36.000
4. 0001    00:24:37.000
5. 0003    00:24:41.000

and so on. But calling "select * from fls119_platzierung" gives me a place 12 for number 6 instead of 1

Answer (score 0):

You should use local variables (`declare v_variable datatype`) inside the stored routines instead of the user defined variables (`@variable`). The user defined variables keep their values throughout the process and in your example the initialization of the variables is outside the routine leading to unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer.
If i use local variables, how can i keep the last place number?
I have to distinguish if two participants have the same final time, they reach the same place (for instance place three). the next one got the fifth place, so the fourth place is not included...

Not sure, variable initialization is the problem.
The initialization works, i think. I'm just wondering that start_6 is updated with place 12 instead of 1. The return value of FortyTwo gave me the correct result. So number 6 on first place and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the primary index on fls119_platzierung. 
So number '0006' has two entries! One with the correct place '1' and one with '12' as place.
So the question changes a little bit. Why is the first record from my select statement executed a second time?